# Isolated points in a cubic

Tags: general-topology, algebra-precalculus

It is a known fact that many cubics have an isolated point. However, common plotters (Wolfram, Desmos and others) do not indicate this isolated point in their graphs.

The cubic $$9y^2=9x^3-24x^2+13x-2$$ has an isolated point. Determine it and justify your answer.

NOTE.-You can verify that your plotter does not indicate the position of the required isolated point.

Comment: I wonder why my post hasn't appeared on the usual list of questions. The problem is well posed and has a solution. On the existence of isolated points in cubic curves (necessarily not elliptical) more than one mathematician has ignored this fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Given $9y^2 = (x-2)(3x-1)^2$, clearly $(\frac13, 0)$ is a solution.  However in any small enough nbd of $x=\frac13$, the RHS is obviously negative, so there cannot be any real $y$ satisfying this, hence this is an isolated point..

Comment: @Piquito Not sure why you think I do not believe you in whatever part of your statement. in any case the post appeared normally for me, though i did not find any other comment other than yours.